# Can Unity Load Assemblies other than current folder

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

My Unity configuration has following structure which works fine.

```
  <unity>
    <namespace name="My.Interface"/>
    <namespace name="SomeType.Class1"/>
    <assembly name="My.Interface"/>
    <assembly name="SomeType.Class1"/>
    <container name="Class1">
      <register type="ICommon" mapTo="Class1" name="Class1">
        <lifetime type="ContainerControlledLifetimeManager" />
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
```

But what if my assemblies are in a subfolder. How do I define?

Something like:

```
  <assembly name="SomeType.Class1" path= "/Subfolder/SomeType.Class1">
```

Comment: If you switch to code based configuration, there is no limitation in where you  can load assemblies from.

Comment: @Steven, In that case I have to add all dlls as reference to my project which I am trying to avoid

Comment: No, you don't. You can load assemblies dynamically in code as well.

Comment: And why are you trying to avoid to reference assemblies from your Composition Root? The [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) will reference everything anyway. There is typically little reason to do dynamic assembly loading at that point.